# Playback stutter ubuntu 19.10

Tags: video

I'm wondering if anyone else has had for example, youtube videos completely stop/stutter for 1-2s after a notification from for example an application like discord installed through the ubuntu software store. I am going mad as i can't even find any posts on this.

It happens specifically when i get discord notifications. Happens on multiple websites including Twitch aswell.

I have 0 gnome extensions and I basically haven't added any other programs or customized anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also i should add I use Firefox as included in the installation. I have not tested with any other notification than discord because its so easy to replicate. The stuttering happens everytime, it never does it otherwise.

Comment: can you edit your first post with the output of `sudo inxi -bmn`

Comment: This happens to me as well. What CPU do you have?